# How to sum 2 input numbers and submit when use Typescript Form Group

Tags: html, angular, typescript, calculated-columns

I have this ts code

```
item: Products[] = [];
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    'Quantity': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    'Price': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    'Total': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
});
```

My functiion submit

```
onAdd(){
    console.log(this)
}
```

Html code:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onAdd()" >

    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input formControlName="Quantity" id="Quantity " type="number">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input formControlName="Price" id="Price" type="number">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
     <div style="text-align:left;">
      Subtotal:
      <input formControlName="Total" id="Subtotal" type="number"> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

1. I want to calculate automatic total = Quantity *  Price
2. Submit my value total.

Comment: <input formControlName="Quantity" id="Quantity " type="number"> [(ngModel)]="Quantity"      <input formControlName="Price" id="Price" type="number" [(ngModel)]="Quantity">     <input formControlName="Total" id="Subtotal" type="number" [value]="Quantity*Unit_price">  But when i use this, on submit my value is null

Answer (score 0):

to get total you need to add [(ngModel)] to your input and make a function which has add logic. 
and call that function in your subtotal value like

```
  <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onAdd()" >

        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input formControlName="Quantity" id="Quantity " type="number">
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input formControlName="Price" id="Price" type="number">
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
         <div style="text-align:left;">
          Subtotal:
<input formControlName="Total" type="text" value='{{ getSum() }}' [(ngModel)]="finalvalue"/>

        </div>
      </div>
```

you can always bind the function using binding property {{}}

and you need to send this [(ngModel)]="finalvalue" to your onAdd() function

Comment: You ask me to change like this ?<input formControlName="Quantity" id="Quantity " type="number"> [(ngModel)]="Quantity"      <input formControlName="Price" id="Price" type="number" [(ngModel)]="Quantity">     <input formControlName="Total" id="Subtotal" type="number"   [(ngModel)]="finalvalue" value='{{ getSum() }}'>

Comment: yes where you want to show total value you need to add there

Comment: ERROR TypeError: _co.getSum is not a function
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]

Comment: check function name properly there might be typing mistake

Comment: ERROR TypeError: _co.getSum is not a function
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]

Comment: I write     <input formControlName="Subtotal" type="text" value='{{ getSum() }}' [(ngModel)]="finalvalue"/>

Comment: This error is usually typing error, or just restart your ng serve server one again

Comment: And what about ts file ?

Comment: I restart but nothing change

Comment: onAdd() {
    let products = [];
    let newProduct = new Products(
      this.myForm.value
    );
    console.log(newProduct)    quantity and price submit correctly, total is ""

Comment: You need to add getSum function in your ts file to and add our adding logic there like Quantity + price

Comment: getSum() {
   let subtotal = 0;
    for (let p of this.products) {
     subtotal = p.Price * p.Quantity;
    }
    console.log(subtotal)
    return subtotal;
  }

Comment: <input formControlName="Total" type="text" value='getSum()' [(ngModel)]="Total"/>
In console Total is NaN

Comment: and in input show this function () {        var subtotal = 0;        for (var _i = 0, _a = this.products; _i < _a.length; _i++) {            var p = _a[_i];            subtotal = p.Unit_price * p.Quantity;        }        console.log(subtotal);        return subtotal;    }